# Alamofire Post Request Error

Tags: swift, alamofire

i am new in swift and i make an Alamofire POST request and i have the same message (FAILURE: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003 "Response status code was unacceptable: 404" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status code was unacceptable: 404})
i try different ways but the same result appear`

```
   Alamofire.request(.POST,"http://api.programize.me/2/projects/alraqem/api/v0/book/create",parameters: ["book_name": bookName,"book_specificaton": bookInfo,"book_photo": base64String ,"book_price": bookPrice,"users_user_id":userID,"deals_deal_id": dammyDeal],headers: ["Authorization": "Token kjsfjksabfjkfbvkfkjasfnvjkfnvkvKASDFHJXRESKBkjb"]).validate().responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            self.indicator.hidden = true
          print("i am happy again")

        ////////////////////////////
        case .Failure:
            self.indicator.hidden = true
            print("not")
            debugPrint(response.result)

        }}`
```

Comment: A 404 is a `Not Found` error. Make sure that the URL is correct

Comment: Postman is your friend.

Comment: thanks for your replay ,,, the link is work fine ,,, i try it on firefox and it add books perfectly to the database

Comment: i make it like this   Alamofire.request(.GET,"http://api.programize.me/2/projects/alraqem/api/v0/book/create/\(newName.text!)/\(newInfo.text!)/\(base64String)/\(newPrice.text!)/\(CurrentUserSingleton.getUserID()!)/\(dammyDeal)/kjsfjksabfjkfbvkfkjasfnvjkfnvkvKJBKJKJBKBkjb").validate().responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
         print("ok")
            case .Failure:
                print("not")
                debugPrint(response.result) }} but it give me: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @LucaDavanzo can you give me more help here?